# AWS opswork cloud formation unable to import

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I am trying to import the cloud formation template for a Opswork VPC as per the guide here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-opsworks-in-the-virtual-private-cloud/

I tried importing but it keeps telling me that

```
The following resource types are not supported for resource import: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment,AWS::EC2::Route,AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation,AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry,AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry,AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry,AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry,AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry,AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry,AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation,AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry,AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation,AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation,AWS::EC2::Route
```

[image]

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the current [resources types that support import operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html)

[Feature request to increase import operation resource type coverage](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/276)

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating your CloudFormation stack, ensure you're using the "With new resource (standard)" option, rather than the "With existing resources (import resources)" option.